# Decrypt or Validate Signature on Azure Mobile Services Token on the server side

Tags: node.js, azure, encryption, azure-mobile-services

After following the [guide](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx) for creating a custom identity provider for azure mobile services I can easily generate the appropriate tokens.  The code is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
var userAuth = {
  user: { userId : userId },
  token: zumoJwt(expiry, aud, userId, masterKey)
}
response.send(200, userAuth);
```

The definitions for the parameters and code for zumoJwt are located at the link.  Azure automatically decodes the token and populates the user on the request object which is what I'd like to simulate.

Basically I'd like to to decrypt the token on the serverside via Node (not .net).

Comment: carlos pointed me in the right direction. my specific code is below if you want to know one way to validate the signature in node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens aren't really encrypted - they're just signed. The tokens have the [JWT format](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-goland-json-web-token-00.html) (line breaks added for clarity):

```
<header>, base64-encoded
"."
<envelope>, base64-encoded
"."
<signature>, base64-encoded
```

If you want to decode (not decrypt) the token in node, you can split the value in the `.` character, take the first two members, base64-decode them (`var buffer = new Buffer(part, 'base64')`), and convert the buffer to string (`buffer.toString('utf-8')`).

If you want to validate the token, just follow the same steps you need to re-sign the first two parts of the token (header + '.' + envelope) with the master key, in the same way that the token was created, and compare it with the signature you received on the original token.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer with regards to auzre mobile services. I wasn't familiar with the JWT format but finally made all these connections after posting my question.  I will accept your answer and will post what I specifically coded for my situation to maybe help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing to validate the token is the following (boiled down).  This seems to be about what the azure mobile services is doing on routes that require authorization.

```
var jws = require('jsw');   // https://github.com/brianloveswords/node-jws 

function userAuth() {
    var token = ''; // get token as header or whatever
    var key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(global.masterKey + "JWTSig").digest('binary');  
    if (!jws.verify(token,key)) { 
      // invalid token logic
    }  else {
       var decode = jws.decode(token)
       req.user = {
          userId: decode.payload.uid.split(';')[0].split('::')[0]
       };
       next();
    }
}

app.use(authChecker);
```